# "Binning" n samples from Gaussian

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say we have $X_1, \dots, X_n$ i.i.d. Gaussian random variables (w.m.a. mean $0$, variance $1$). We also construct $m$ equally spaced, contiguous intervals $\{[x_i, x_{i+1}]\}_{i=1}^{m}$  with $x_1 = 0$ and $x_{m+1}=r$ for some $r>0$. I'm interested in knowing the expected number of intervals (in terms of $r$, $n$) that contain *exactly* one value from this random sample. This reminds me of the balls and urns problem, but where the urns are not equally probable. I'm looking for hints, not necessarily full solutions!

Comment: Your notation for the bins implies that there aren't bins for negative values of $x$, but I think the meaning of tiling the real line with bins of width r, with x=0 the border between two bins, is clear enough without having to shove it into some notation.

Comment: I'm just interested in the problem where there are bins for non-negative values of $x$. Not sure what you mean by "having to shove it into some notation"...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I definitely misread your question.

Comment: Regarding "shove it into some notation", there's egg on my face because your text description matched your notation perfectly, and I just misread the former. I was just expressing my sentiment that descriptions in a language are often a lot clearer than "precise" notation. But others might disagree with me, and its a matter of taste (on top of me being wrong here).

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not so important that the distribution here is Gaussian. The binning procedure turns this from a continuous random variable $X$ into a discrete random variable $B$ over the integers, each integer corresponding to a bin, and where the probability mass function is
$$
i < m: p_i = p\left(B=i\right) = \int_{ri}^{r(i+1)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx. \\
i = m: p_m = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} p_i
$$
After this translation you have an random variable taking on $m+1$ integer values in the range $[0,m]$, from which you will sample $n$ times -- this is just a multinomial distribution. In the standard multinomial distribution language, there is an $(m+1)$-sided die that is being rolled $n$ times, and the probability of any possible outcome -- a set of integers numbers $n_i \geq 0$ for $0 \leq m$ -- can be found in a any reference, or derived easily. The next step is simply to translate "the number of bins with one entry" into a function of these $n_i$ values, and then compute the expectation by summing over all possibilities.

---

When summing over all possibilities, it's best to use the general identity that
$$
E[N_1] = \sum_{\textrm{all possible } n_i} N_1(n_i) p(n_i)
$$
In other words, you don't need to start off by writing a complicated summation "here's the sum over all states with $N_1(n_i) = 1$, here's the sum over all states with $N_1(n_i) = 2$, etc." Now, the formula for $N(n_i)$ is
$$
N(n_i) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} I(n_k=1)
$$
Inserting this into the summation, and rearranging,
$$
E[N_1] = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \sum_{\textrm{all possible } n_i} I(n_k=1) p(n_i)
$$
The summation over all $n_i$ values includes a summation over $n_k$, and the indicator function picks out a particular value. The constraint on the summation over $n_i$ is just that $\sum_i n_i = n$, and if $n_k=1$ then $\sum_{i \neq k} = n-1$. Thus,
$$
E[N_1] = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \left( \sum_{n_k=1,\textrm{all possible } n_{i \neq k}, \sum_{i\neq k} n_i = n-1} p(n_i) \right)
$$
Given the form for $p(n_i)$, there is a way to exactly evaluate that inner summation, and you'll end up with a pretty simple formula for $E[N_1]$ in terms of the probabilities $p_i$. Hint: substitute in the probability $p(n_i)$ for the multinomial distribution, substitute in the value of $n_k$, and look to use the multinomial theorem to simplify the summation over $n_{i \neq k}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! This makes sense. For large $n$, $m$, it seems like  summing over all these possibilities could be unwieldy. Is my intuition wrong here? Maybe there's some nice simplification.

Comment: @lfowl I did not attempt to calculate this out, but I wouldn't be surprised if there was a closed form answer as a function of $p_i$ and $n$. In particular, each term in the sum is proportional to the the multinomial p.m.f., which involves binomial coefficients and probabilities taken to integer powers, and there are of course many series identities of that form.

Comment: And then maybe after that, if you were to plug back in the relationship between each $p_i$ and the Gaussian distribution, something nice about the $r$ dependence would come out of that, but my guess is that you wouldn't be so lucky and that will just become a bit of a mess.

Comment: I guess the tricky part for me is enumerating all the orientations. For example, enumerating all the ways to get exactly one value in exactly 3 bins...

Comment: I've added a bit more to the answer that may address that.